# Stop link redirect jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem, I tried several ways to stop the propagation of a link but without success. Maybe someone who could help me and will see a bug on my code.

By the way, I use .on('click') because some link will be add on the DOM with ajax request.

```js
$('.facette_mobile').on('click', '.facette_enfant a', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // or event.stopPropagation()
});

// OR
$('.facette_mobile').on('click', '.facette_enfant a', function() {
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="facette_mobile">  
  <div class="facette_enfant">
    <a href="http://www.google.fr" data-id="3" data-intitule="Test 3" >Link to google </a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: your both code are working fine. Just add jQuery library before it.(I have added it in your question and now codes started working)

Comment: thanks for your answer @AlivetoDie. However I have jquery library loaded before my script but nothing work unfortunately.

src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"

Comment: Are you doing it live somewhere? please provide me link. Also check your browser console tab. May be you have any other jQuery error there already present

Comment: @AlivetoDie here is a link : https://dev.iciformation.fr/bilans-de-competences.html

1) Turn on your toggle device toolbar to be on a mobile iphone 6/7/8.  
2) Click on the button "Filtrer", select the first "li" (REGIONS) then click on a link in the list

Comment: direct do :-`$('.facette_enfant a').on('click', function(event) {`

Comment: @AlivetoDie, sorry I'm not sure to understand what you want to say

Comment: you have one jquery error on your page. check browser tab:- `GET https://static.iciformation.fr/domaine/photos/bilan-de-competences.jpg net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID` . remove it and your code will work

Answer (score 1):

I found the error, in fact I called another js file and inside there was short code about link click. I removed it and everything works fine now !

Thank you for your answers guys !

Comment: Thank you for letting us know! You can always still upvote the answers to show your appreciation :) 
& Of course, welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 1):

Just call `.preventDefault()` when the Click Event happens.

```js
$("a").on("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
```

**Addition for Mousewheel-Click**

This alone will not work for the mousewheel click because it's not the same Event as click. Maybe you could use `.mousedown()` and `.mouseup()` because these Event's are triggered even for Mousewheel-Click.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Jquery for this (even if some links are added through ajax)

First part is an helper function to add the eventhandler after a specific event, in this case DOMContentLoaded.
Second part is just the vanilla js variant of what you already had

```js
function addEventHandler(elem, eventType, handler) {
      if (elem.addEventListener)
        elem.addEventListener (eventType, handler, false);
      else if (elem.attachEvent)
        elem.attachEvent ('on' + eventType, handler); 
}
    addEventHandler(document, 'DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var link = document.getElementsByClassName('link');
        link[0].addEventListener('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        });
});
```

```html
    <a class="link" href="www.google.com">Go to google</a>
```